# Android. Запрашивать у FusedLocation координаты в фоновом потоке, а обновление не уснет?

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

1)Хочу через `IntentService` запрашивать координаты через `FusedLocation API`. Хорошо, запросы раз в минуту в отдельном потоке не уснут, а может получится так что я буду запрашивать координаты, а процесс обновления координат уснет и мне просто будут даваться раз в минуту не актуальные одинаковые координаты?

2) Почему то ни где не могу найти примера работы `FusedLocation` в `IntentService` (может так никто не делает?), ведь запрос координат в фоне это довольно распространенная задача, может у кого-нибудь есть собственная реализация или пример?

Comment: 2) никто так не делает - IntentService предназначен для выполнения **единичной** операции в фоновом потоке. После отработки метода onHandleIntent() он умирает. https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: А как тогда получают координаты в фоновом потоке, чтоб поток не засыпал?

Comment: Обычно просто подписываются (выставляют листенер) на **изменение координат**, А не спрашивают координаты непрерывно

Comment: А подписываются через FusedLocation? И слушатель где реализуетса чтоб не отключался сам по себе в фоне?

Comment: смотрите update в моём ответе

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** Что бы прослушивать изменение месторасположения нужно -

1) **в Activity реализуете след. интерфейсы**

```
 public class YourtActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
  LocationListener {

  private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
     .setInterval(60 * 60 * 1000).setFastestInterval(10 * 1000);
  //...
```

2)**В методе onCreate инициализируете своего клиента** -

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

 }
```

3) **и устанавливаете слушателя**

```
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST, new LocationListener() {

      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
         // здесь помещаете свою логику

      }
    });     
  }
```

Comment: При такой реализации ничего не отрубится и не уснет, если телефон не будут трогать в течении получаса?

Comment: пока система не убьёт сервис из-за нехватки ресурсов, ничего не *уснёт*). Но я бы советовал прислушаться к комментарию к вопросу  –  metalurgus-а

Comment: @Gennady, почитайте о foreground services. Системы их не должна убивать при нехватке памяти.

Comment: да нет же всю логику изменения координат, по хорошему, нужно реализовывать в 
*com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener*

Comment: @s_klepcha, вроде как гугл рекомендует Google Maps API..

Comment: ну вот это пример реализующий  Google Maps API.

Comment: @s_klepcha, не заметил, что Вы автор ответа) Ваше сообщение к чему написано ? "
   
 
да нет же всю логику изменения координат, по хорошему, нужно реализовывать в com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener"

Comment: это ответ на комментарий Gennady

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы при закрытом приложенни, сервис продолжал собирать координаты и не отрубался, мне кажется что Ваша реализация, при закрытом приложении долго не проживет. Или я не прав?

Comment: ну да, а вам не жалко батарейки пользовательского телефона? ;)

Comment: конечно нет, слушать то изменения локации я умею, я не умею сделать так чтоб данные в фоне собирались в отдельном потоке и не отрубались.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте о Foreground Service. 
(он будет продолжать работать, даже когда пользователь закроет ваше приложение)

[Foreground service читайте](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/165-urok-100-service-intentservice-foreground-avtozagruzka-servisa)

Comment: А IntentService для этих целей почему не подойдет? Мне кажется Foreground Service будет излишним для простого сбора координат в другом потоке, я не прав?

Comment: Это несколько разные вещи. В ссылке, что я Вам дал написано об этом.